# POVRAY - Is there a way to collect environment data?

Tags: povray

I am currently dispersing photons in a pov ray environment, however what I would like to do is collect properties of each photon and their interactions with the scene, in other words collect information on each photon trajectory. How do you think i could go about doing this?

Thank you very much.